# updating table in entity framework 4 /mvc 3!

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

could you help with this? I bet this isn't any tough one..but am new to EF and   facing a weekend deadline. I want to update a table with values.. but the primary key is   identity column. So my task is like this.. if it exists, update.. if it doesn't add to the
table.. this is my code..and am stuck in this else part..!

Table structure is like this

Primary Key table - System: SystemId, SystemName

Foreign Key table - SystemConfiguration: SystemConfigurationId, SystemId, SystemRAM, SystemHard-Disk

```
        public void SaveSystemConfigurations(SystemConfiguration systemConfig)
         {
              var config = (from s in Context.SystemConfiguration 
                       where s.SystemId == systemConfig.SystemId
                            select s).FirstOrDefault();

             if (config == null)
             {
                 Context.SystemConfigurations.AddObject(systemConfig);
                 Context.SaveChanges();
             }
             else
             {
                // EntityKey systemConfigKey= new EntityKey("systemConfig", "systemConfigId", config.SystemConfigurationId);
                 Context.SystemConfigurations.Attach(systemConfig);
                Context.SaveChanges();

           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        public void SaveSystemConfigurations(SystemConfiguration systemConfig)
         {
              var config = (from s in Context.SystemConfiguration 
                       where s.SystemId == systemConfig.SystemId
                            select s).FirstOrDefault();

             if (config == null)
             {
                 Context.SystemConfigurations.AddObject(systemConfig);
             }
             else
             {
                config.Attribute = value; // Do your update here

           }
           Context.SaveChanges();
       }
```

Edit. It should be config not systemConfig.

Comment: intellisense do not give any .Attibute?!

Comment: Yes. .Attribute is just an example. Replace .Attribute with the Attribute you want to update. Eg. config.DateModified = DateTime.Now; etc.

Comment: thanks.. ysrb..this works like a charm..!  am further researching if theres a better solution..rather than manually setting so many columns..

Comment: @hillary what are you trying to do? You don't need to set many columns because the config will have the properties populated from the database.

Comment: ysrb.. this is what I meant.. by manually setting every column.           else
             {   config.SystemIsBlueToothEnabled= systemConfig.SystemIsBlueToothEnabled;
                 config.SystemCPU= systemConfig.SystemCPU;
                 config.SystemMaxRam= systemConfig.SystemMaxRam;  }       Isnt this what u meant?

Comment: @Hillary Yes. That's I think the only way. If you automate it, you won't be able to select which attributes not to be copied.

Comment: thnx ysrb..i will mark this as ans since that what helped me. maybe the other is an elegant solution but i could not get it to work.. for now, i will stop with this.

Answer (score 1):

The [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx)  method will apply scalar attributes to an entity that matches the same key.  My assumption is that you are modifying a real entity (an object that has a valid entity key).

This would work:

```
var eSet  = config.EntityKey.EntitySetName;
Context.ApplyCurrentValues(eSet, systemConfig);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: is this what u mean?      EntityKey key= new EntityKey("Context.SystemConfigurations","SystemConfigurationId", config.SystemConfigurationId);
                 var eSet = key.EntitySetName;
                 Context.ApplyCurrentValues(eSet, systemConfig);  but no, this isnt working..

Comment: wont work until i set systemConfig.SystemConfigurationId = key.value.. but why do we have to manually do it?! am i missing someth!

Comment: If you give me a little more background about where systemConfig came from I will update my post and give you a more "modern" solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void SaveSystemConfigurations(SystemConfiguration systemConfig)
     {    
    var context = new EntitiesModel(); 
    //here is the name of the partial class created on the Context area of the edmx designer.cs
    var config = (from s in context.SystemConfiguration 
                   where s.SystemId == systemConfig.SystemId
                        select s).FirstOrDefault();
    context.ApplyCurrentValues(config.EntityKey.EntitySetName, systemConfig);
    // systemConfig comes from the view with values set by the user
    // you dont have to manually need to map one value at the time
    context.SaveChanges();
    }
```